# JavaME Vector is not working properly

Tags: java, vector

Well firstly i am using NetBeans IDE. There is a client that one thread of it receives messages from the server and puts them in a Vector and another thread handles them. MessageListener and MessageHandler are the ones. So the problem is that the first message that it receives it is working good, but for the next message when it calls the method byte[] getFirstMessage() it returns byte with values of 0`s.

In my oppinion the problem is either with the Vector addElement method that it adds the second message to the index 1 and not 0 although it deletes the contents of vector`s first element as soon as it passes that data to the MessageHandler or that i use local variables in some methods. P.S it should have been the message queue.

MessageListener.java

```
package org.rebirth;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class MessageListener implements Runnable{

Vector v; 
int size = 0;
Connections con;
byte[] buffer = new byte[100000];
boolean noErrors = true;

public MessageListener(Connections con){
    v = new Vector(50,10);

    this.con = con;

    Thread thr = new Thread(this);
    thr.start();
}

public void run(){

    while(noErrors){            
        try{   

            listenForData();
            Thread.sleep(1);            
        }catch(Exception exc){
            exc.printStackTrace();  
            noErrors = false;
        }
    }
}

public void listenForData() throws IOException{


    con.fill(buffer,(byte)0);
    System.out.println("Trying to receive data");
    // InputStream                                                             
    con.in.read(buffer);
    System.out.println("Data received id "+con.ReadInt3Bytes(buffer,1));
    v.addElement(buffer);
    size++;

    if(v.isEmpty()){
        System.out.println("empty");
    }


}

public byte[] getFirstMessage(){
    if(v.size()>0){
        byte[] data = (byte[]) v.firstElement();
        v.removeElementAt(0); 
        size--;

        System.out.println("first byte element "+(int)data[0]);

        return data;
    }
    return null;
}

}
```

Messagehandler.java

```
 package org.rebirth;

 import java.util.*;
 import javax.microedition.lcdui.game.*;

public class MessageHandler implements Runnable{

Vector v;
MessageListener lst;
Connections con;
int vienas = 1;

public MessageHandler(Vector v,MessageListener lst){
    this.v = v;
    this.lst = lst;
    this.con = lst.con;

    Thread thr = new Thread(this);
    thr.start();
}


public void run(){
    while(true){
        try{

            if(!v.isEmpty()){                    
                handleMessages();

            }
            Thread.sleep(10);            
        }catch(Exception exc){}
    }
}

public void handleMessages(){
   // vectordsfds

    int id;

    byte [] gotByte = lst.getFirstMessage();        
    id=con.ReadInt3Bytes(gotByte,1);       
    System.out.println("handler id: "+id);

    // call a method to handle received message;
    handleMessage(id,gotByte);          
}

public void handleMessage(int id,byte[] gotByte){
    switch(id){            

        case 62:
            // GameServerList

            con.serverNumber = (int)gotByte[4];
            System.out.println("Servers "+con.serverNumber);        

                    int nri = 6;
                    for(int i=0;i<con.serverNumber;i++){

                        nameLength = (int)gotByte[nri];
                        nri+=1;
                        con.serverName[i] = new String(gotByte, nri, nameLength);
                        nri+=nameLength;
                        int ipLength = (int)gotByte[nri];
                        nri+=1;
                        con.serverIp[i] = new String(gotByte, nri, ipLength);
                        nri+=ipLength;
                        con.online[i] = con.ReadInt3Bytes(gotByte,nri);
                        nri+=3;
                        con.maxOnline[i] = con.ReadInt3Bytes(gotByte,nri);

                        System.out.println("Server name " +con.serverName[i]);
                        System.out.println("ip "+con.serverIp[i]);
                        System.out.println("online "+con.online[i]);
                        System.out.println("max online "+con.maxOnline[i]);
                        nri+=4;
                    }

            break;

        case 64:
            //GameVersion


            int success = (int)gotByte[4];


            if(success == 1){
                con.version=true;
                System.out.println("Version match!");

        }else{
                System.out.println("version does not match");
                System.out.println(success);
            }

        break;




    }
}


}
```

EDIT 2: I added a statement InputStream class available() method before reading the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am surprised it works even sometimes. If I am reading the sources right, you are using the same buffer instance for all incoming messages. Vector.addElement does not create a copy of the buffer, it just saves the reference passed as param, so listenForData running in while(noErrors) loop will clear the (one and only) buffer with zeros as soon as it runs again. And when it runs again depedsn on how threads are scheduled, so sometimes the message listener gets the buffer with real data and sometimes with zeros.

Also I'm not sure that CLDC Vector is, unlike in J2SE, synchronized. So I think vector access should be synchronized.
And also I'm not sure what type of connections you are using, but reading bytes from stream without checking return value and without knowing how many bytes you should read seems like a bit unreliable piece of code...

EDIT: by "knowing how many bytes you should read" I did not mean using available() function, which is likely to return 0 for many types of streams. When read() returns, it may (and it often does) read less bytes than requested, so you can never be sure if you have enough data in buffer to work with, unless you known how much data you are waiting and you keep reading until you have them. I think you should define a protocol, it can be as simple as fixed-size messages if it fits you needs.

Answer (score 0):

It is not so trivial to understand what happens with your code exactly. However method `listenForData()` indeed adds byte array filled by zeros to your vector:

```
con.fill(buffer,(byte)0); 
......
v.addElement(buffer);
```

So, although you are new here and I would like to welcome you and to wish you a lot of success I would like to ask you some questions.

1. do you know that J2ME is obsolete? Take a look on Android OS if you want to program form mobile devices.
2. Do you really think that JDK classes (like `Vector`) contain bugs that you can discover by writing your first program?
3. Did you hear about debuggers? Try to debug your code to understand why it does not work.
4. If you want to ask question and get a good answer take a look on [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Good luck.

Comment: 1. Yes I know that. I am only 17 years old and by coding Java ME i seek experience first. 2. no and it`s not my first program :) Thank you.

Comment: @Danis If you only want to seek for first experience please do not use Java ME but use Java SE. This runs on a desktop environment which is easier to debug and handle.

Comment: con.fill(buffer,(byte)0); is ment for filling that array with 0`s. I know it is not the best way to do it. @Uwe Plonus i am seeking gaming experience with my team. We are developing 2D MMORPG game on phones. Later we will move on to Android 3D but for now we just need experience in game development. We are actually developing this game for 3rd countries who still use old phones to play.